# Creating array of objects with specific key taken out of appended object

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

Initially, there is an empty array, and later some objects appear:

```js
const aggregator = [];

const product1 = {"id": "prod1", "contents": {"key1": "value1"}};
const product2 = {"id": "prod2", "contents": {"key2": "value2"}};
```

How to add these objects to the `aggregator` array so that they are like:

```js
{
    "aggregator": [
    {
        "id": "prod1",
        "contents": {
            "key1": "value1"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "prod2",
        "contents": {
            "key2": "value2"
        }
    }
    ]
}
```

My approach was using the spread operator:

```js
aggregator = [...aggregator, {product1}];
aggregator = [...aggregator, {product2}];
```

But that way I got something like:

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify(aggregator));
/*
'[
{"product1":{"id":"prod1","contents":{"key1":"value1"}}},
{"product2":{"id":"prod2","contents":{"key2":"value2"}}}
]'
*/
```

which is not exactly something I wanted to achieve.

Comment: The difference is, the stringified output has `product1` etc. used as key, and the `id` is inside the value (object). I'd like to have the `id` taken out of the value and to become the key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the object `{product1}`. `product1` is already an object, you don't have to wrap it inside another object.

You don't need the spread operator, use the `push()` method to add to an array.

```js
const aggregator = [];

const product1 = {"id": "product1", "contents": {"key1": "value1"}};
const product2 = {"id": "product2", "contents": {"key2": "value2"}};

aggregator.push(product1);
aggregator.push(product2);
console.log(aggregator);
```